# How to add a 'Content-Type' header to an HTTP response with PHP fatal error in IIS?

Tags: php, mysql, iis, mysqli, utf-8

I use a stack of technologies Windows 10, web server IIS 10, RDBMS 'MySQL' 8.0, PHP 8.1.10.

---

My question was considered a duplicate of the following question: '[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)'. Here are my objections. I don't have a problem with UTF-8 encoding: 'MySQL' returns the response in the correct encoding, PHP + web-server IIS transmits this data correctly to the browser.

My problem is that the web server IIS does not transmit the HTTP 'Content-Type' header in the HTTP response (in case of a PHP fatal error), which is why the browser displays the correct data in the wrong encoding. Thus my question is not a duplicate.

---

I took the [script from the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), changed it to fit my parameters:

```php
<?php
// mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "testdb");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
```

and put it in a file `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php`. In the browser ('Microsoft Edge' on 'Chromium' engine) at the address `localhost/testdb.php` I received the desired response:

```
Hello, dear MySQL user!
```

In the browser developer tools, I made sure that there is a header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` in the HTTP response. In the `php.ini` file I have the settings:

```
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

After that I initiated 'PHP Fatal error' by stopping the RDBMS server `mysqld.exe`. In the browser at the address `localhost/testdb.php` I received the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: ÐŸÐ¾Ð´ÐºÐ»ÑŽÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð½Ðµ ÑƒÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð»ÐµÐ½Ð¾, Ñ‚.Ðº. ÐºÐ¾Ð½ÐµÑ‡Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÐºÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿ÑŒÑŽÑ‚ÐµÑ€ Ð¾Ñ‚Ð²ÐµÑ€Ð³ Ð·Ð°Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ñ Ð½Ð° Ð¿Ð¾Ð´ÐºÐ»ÑŽÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php(3): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'testdb')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php on line 3
```

In the browser developer tools, I saw that there is no header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` in the HTTP response. Because of this, the browser displayed the body of the HTTP response in encoding 'Windows-1252' instead of 'UTF-8'. Because of this, part of the error message was displayed with [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

**My question is:** how to add a header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` to an HTTP response with 'PHP fatal error' in IIS? (So that the error message is displayed in the browser in the correct encoding 'UTF-8'.)

I know that it is possible to use the construction `try-catch`:

```php
<?php
// mysqli
try {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "testdb");
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "<pre>", $e, "</pre>";
}
```

and then the browser will receive an HTTP response with the header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`:

```
mysqli_sql_exception: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php(4): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'testdb')
#1 {main}
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to add a header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` specifically to an HTTP response with 'PHP fatal error'.

You can also change the encoding in the `php.ini` file using the setting:

```
default_charset = "Windows-1251"
```

In this case, PHP will return an error message to the browser in the encoding 'Windows-1251' and the browser will display the message correctly in this encoding. But I want to work with text in encoding 'UTF-8' since encoding 'Windows-1251' is legacy.

I also tried to configure `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".js" />
            <remove fileExtension=".css" />
            <remove fileExtension=".html" />
            <remove fileExtension=".htm" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css; charset=utf-8" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".htm" mimeType="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".php" mimeType="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        </staticContent>
        <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` did not appear in the HTTP response with 'PHP fatal error'.

---

I used the error handling method suggested by @YourCommonSense:

```
<?php
include 'error_handling.php';
// mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "testdb");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'Hello, dear MySQL user!' AS _message FROM DUAL");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo htmlentities($row['_message']);
```

File `error_handling.php`:

```
<?php
function exception_handler(Throwable $exception) {
    echo "<pre>", $exception, "</pre>";
}
set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

The result in the browser (the same as with the method `try-catch`):

```
mysqli_sql_exception: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testdb.php(4): mysqli->__construct('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'testdb')
#1 {main}
```

Yes, it improves the beauty of the code and makes error handling easier. This is a workaround to solve my problem, I will use it. But this is still not the answer to my original question. And my question is not a duplicate of the question [How do I catch a PHP fatal (`E_ERROR`) error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-e-error-error).

Comment: Do ```header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");``` in your PHP code before the first actual content output?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @Hartmut-Holzgraefe I didn't write about it, but I tried it. This does not work for me in this case. How can this work in case of a [fatal exception error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_exception_error)?

Comment: Does this help? https://maideveloper.com/blog/how-to-set-default-encoding-in-iis

Comment: ÐŸÐ¾Ð´ÐºÐ»ÑŽÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ ... is Mojibake for Подключение... -- You were expecting Cyrillic?  See Mojibake in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @IlyaChalov you don't really need it. Fatal errors are **not intended to be shown on-screen** in the first place. In case of a fatal error a generic "Temporary maintenance" banner must be shown without any particular details.

Comment: @RickJames the problem here is different. The encoding is all right. The header is wrong. I made a mistake editing the title, and reverted it back.

Comment: @JacobMulquin It doesn't work for me. Isn't `system.web` a legacy for IIS 6? I didn't find such an element in the [Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/).

Comment: @RickJames You haven't read my question to the end. Below is a sample of the correct output of this message when I used the `try-catch` construct. My question is not a duplicate, I ask you to remove the remark about the duplicate.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have given an error message from the PHP interpreter in my question. This message was displayed by my browser. It says, quote: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception:`. The error is not caught by the program, so it is handled by the interpreter (so it seems to me). Therefore, it is called 'fatal'.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm not going to show this message to end users, I need to see this message in the correct encoding for debugging.

Comment: Speaking of this particular kind of fatal errors, you simply have to have an **exception handler.**  [Like this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#function). So it won't become a fatal error anymore. While speaking of proper fatal errors, you will need a handler for them as well. It can be found in the same article below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248660/discussion-between-ilya-chalov-and-your-common-sense).